# Move Text Cursor to Front or End of Word Using Keyboard in OS X

Tags: macos

In Windows, you can use the combination of ctrl + shift + left / right arrow keys to move the current cursor position to the start or end of the word the cursor is currently on.  Is there a keyboard combination in OS X that does the same thing?

Comment: BTW AFAICT Windows[*] does not have a standard keyboard shortcut to move to the end of the current word. It has a shortcut to move to the beginning of the next word. This makes a difference when you are writing keyboard macros for accessibility.  // ^{Right}=>start of next word; ^{Left}=start of this word,  or previous if already at start of current word.  Shifting  these extends selection. // Note *:   Windows may have changed its standard keyboard shortcuts since OP.   I am currently on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Alt-Left/Right. Although I don't get what you mean by Ctrl-Shift-Left/Right. That selects text in addition to moving the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the option/alt-left arrow and right arrow, most text fields on OS X also accept emacs key bindings, so control-a moves the cursor to the beginning of a line, control-e to the end, etc.